# w3wp.exe The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception - Random restarts

Tags: asp.net, iis, process, iis-7.5, w3wp

We have an asp.net running on IIS 7.5 with elmah error logging. Randomly we get these two event logs at the same time (same second) reporting w3wp restart which logs everyone out. These errors don't make it to elmah, even though elmah logs everything else.

The errors are random, it's not a specific error that causes these w3wp restarts. One error was a failure sending an email because the smtp server timed out. Another error was a null reference exception.

I notice there's a problem when people complain call to say they've been logged out and when I check the event log I see these errors but by then w3wp restarted already and running fine. There's really nothing in the details to help.

This seems to happen under heavy load, when the website is used most heavily but RAM/CPU etc are all fine on the server and I can't find anything else reported at the same time regarding RAM or anything else.

It's not the "rapid fail protection" because the application gets a handful of exceptions a day and the "Rapid Fail" is set to 5 errors in 5 mins, so it's not that either. Never had 5 errors in 5 mins.

These errors don't get reported by elmah so it's almost like the app crashes before the exception can be handled, which I don't understand how.

Also event log sometimes has this log at about the same time (within few seconds) but not for every restart.

> A process serving application pool '' suffered a fatal communication
>   error with the World Wide Web Publishing Service. The process id was
>   ''. The data field contains the error number.

So any ideas what I can check? It occurs randomly, sometimes every few weeks, sometimes 4 times a week.

Source = `.NET Runtime`:

> Application: w3wp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Source = `ASP>NET 4.0.30319`

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>   Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT Process ID: 33264

Comment: Try to use DebugDiag from Microsoft to capture crash dumps.

Comment: @LexLi Is that safe to use on production server? I don't want it slowing down the server or causing further crashes/restarts, etc.

Comment: it is commonly used by Microsoft customers on production servers.

Comment: @lexli Any idea what kind of dump I should set up? Exceptions are random so I can't set up an exception rule. Is there a rule you know specific for w3wp restart?

Comment: try it first on a test server and create a crash rule. That's also what you should do later on the production server.